# Proper way of writing symbol upper and lower boundary?

Tags: equations

Is there a proper in an `equation` enviroment write something similar to this

```
A + 2 = x ,   1 < A < X
```

without manually have to insert the spaces using ~ or something like that?

Comment: I would use either `\quad` or `\qquad` as the spacer. E.g., `$A + 2 = x ,\quad   1 < A < X$`.

Comment: not sure if you want to use that in a text or as a separate formula; but if the latter better put such conditions after a pipe (|) or even in brackets.

Comment: You can also use && in an `align` environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something you intended is in it …

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

with tabbing

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{9em} \= \hspace{11em} \= \\
\> $A + 2 = x$ \> $, 1 < A < X$ \\
\end{tabbing}

or columns in align

\begin{align}
A + 2 &= x  &,  1 < A < X \\
\end{align}

or as @mico menat with quad or qquad

\begin{align}
A + 2 = x \quad, 1 < A < X
\end{align}

or even simple spaces to make it your size

\begin{align}
A + 2 = x \hspace{3em}, 1 < A < X 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```